# How to use R ggplot stat_summary to plot median and quartiles?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

how to change the lower and upper point in this stat summary plot to 25% quartile and 75% quartile?

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + stat_summary(
  mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth),
  fun.ymin = min,
  fun.ymax = max,
  fun.y = median
)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rewriting G5W's solution, using the geom function instead of the stat function:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) +
  geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth),
                  stat = "summary",
                  fun.min = function(z) {quantile(z,0.25)},
                  fun.max = function(z) {quantile(z,0.75)},
                  fun = median)
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + stat_summary(
  mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth),
  fun.min = function(z) { quantile(z,0.25) },
  fun.max = function(z) { quantile(z,0.75) },
  fun = median)
```

[image: Diamonds]

Comment: HI,@DomQ  I crossed this answer and it helped me a lot. Can I ask for a clarification? fun.min receives a vector and returns a number, how does function() knows that you are passing Depth. is the dependent variable y being pass by default? Thanks a lot

Comment: @spleen   `ggplot` will apply `fun.min` to its y value (which was specified as depth). The default function that is used is `min`,  but defining `fun.min` like this allows the use of a different function. `ggplot` knows to apply `fun.min` to its y value.

Comment: what is z in this answer?  I'm trying to adapt this to a slightly different plot, but I have no idea how to specify that the function should be applied to the x value.

Comment: @tnt z is just a placeholder variable. I am *defining* functions to get the upper and lower limit for the bars in the graph.

Comment: @G5W I can't get this solution to work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78208127/add-quantiles-to-geom-density-plot-with-stat-summary

Answer (score 2):

This question already has excellent answers, but I wanted to build on these with more brief solution, as I prefer to keep code for plots short. `stat_summary` can take custom functions, with support for arguments.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Define function to calculate IQR at given quantiles
iqr = function(z, lower = 0.25, upper = 0.75) {
  data.frame(
    y = median(z),
    ymin = quantile(z, lower),
    ymax = quantile(z, upper)
  )
}

# Plot standard IQR
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = iqr)
```

[image]

```r
# Arguments can be accessed with fun.args
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = iqr, fun.args = list(lower = 0.1, upper = 0.9))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>