# Adding labels in ggplot for summary statistics

Tags: r, ggplot2

About 18 months ago, [this helpful exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077199/how-to-use-r-ggplot-stat-summary-to-plot-median-and-quartiles) appeared, with code to show how to produce a plot of median along with interquartile ranges. Here's the code:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) +
geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth),
              stat = "summary",
              fun.ymin = function(z) {quantile(z,0.25)},
              fun.ymax = function(z) {quantile(z,0.75)},
              fun.y = median)
```

Producing this plot:

[image: this plot]

What I'd wonder is how to add labels for the median and IQ ranges, and how to format the bar (color, alpha, etc). I tried calling the plot as an object to see if there were objects within I could then use to call format functions, but nothing was obvious when I looked at it in the r Studio IDE.

Is this even doable? I know I can do a boxplot but that would have to include min/max. I'd like to produce boxplots with just mean/median and IQs.

Comment: You could just preprocess your data--calculate the descriptive stats you're using before plotting, and then use those numbers to make labels

Comment: Also with this: "how to format the bar (color, alpha, etc)" you'll have to be much more specific

Comment: Yes, I did a version where I coded the summary stats then manipulated a dataframe from there to plot. I was hoping to do it all within one ggplot call rather than multiple steps.

Comment: By format I mean...change the color of the bar, change the thickness, transparency. The typical things you can do in ggplot when you have objects to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the formating like you would any ggplot layer, see the [docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_linerange.html) for *Vertical intervals: lines, crossbars & errorbars* in this case. An example of this is the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = diamonds) +
  geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth),
                  stat = "summary",
                  fun.ymin = function(z) {quantile(z,0.25)},
                  fun.ymax = function(z) {quantile(z,0.75)},
                  fun.y = median,
                  size = 4,             # <- adjusts size
                  colour = "red",       # <- adjusts colour
                  alpha = .3)           # <- adjusts transparency
```

[image]

If you want to control formatting for the points and lines individually you need to do as @camille suggests and pre-process your data as `geom_pointrange()` draws a single graphical object so the points and lines are one in the same.

I would suggest something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  summarise(median = median(depth),
            lq = quantile(depth, 0.25),
            uq = quantile(depth, 0.75)) %>% 

  ggplot(aes(cut, median)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=lq, ymax=uq), size = 4, colour = "blue", alpha = .4) +
  geom_point(size = 10, colour = "red", alpha = .8)
```

[image]